# What is the code from the table of enchantments for armor? 

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I wonder why some items have incomplete enchantments like it isn't possible to entchant a boot with fortify alchemy. Is this a bug or a special code? Here is the list of enchantment: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Enchanting_(Skyrim)#Exploit.

Comment: Only true masters can brew a potion with their feet.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a bug. Certain enchants can not be placed on items worn in certain slots. This is done for reasons of balance -  to limit the number of enchants that boost a particular stat based upon the number of items that can be worn simultaneously that increase it.